# Codeigniter update_batch increment value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I am trying to update multiple rows, incrementing its value, from what I know, it is impossible to do this using update_batch() as CI always escape the value when using update_batch(), is this correct, or if there is a way, please elaborate the way as an answer. For example, I have this array:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'product_id' => '1',
        'value' => '5',
    ),
    array(
        'product_id' => '2',
        'value' => '15'
    )
);
```

Now I want to update my table by incrementing column value(INT) by the value in the array where column product_id = product_id in the array.

What I'm doing now is using loops of set like this

```
foreach($array as $a) {
    $this->db->set('value' + $a['value'], FALSE);
    $this->db->where('product_id', $a['product_id'];
    $this->db->update('table');
}
```

However sometimes I will need to update more than 10 rows, and I'm thinking this process will be costly and take a lot of memory, how do i further simplify this method to get the same result ?

All answers are greatly welcome and appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->update_batch();` to update multiple record at once. See this **[codeigniter user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update)** for update query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, but how do I increment the value ? i.e: if in my value column I already has value of 50, if I use update_batch (value=>'5') the value in my table will become 5, while what I want is to become 55

Comment: you need to get old values from db and add new value to it, and create associative array to update in batch.

Comment: Won't that be costlier and heavier compared to using foreach(set and update) on all the arrays ?

Comment: i dont think so. Anyways you are getting old values in `$array`. updating one by one, its better to do once.

Answer (score 0):

IN CODEIGNITER 3/4 There is no solution for update batch arithmetic operations for self field, thus you need to edit the system file as it can be risky but may work for you, open file named db_query_builder.php in path system\database\db_query_builder.php and go to line number 1970, now replace with below code.

```
//if field name in value and +,-,*,/,% in value then apply that to self field
$flag = TRUE;
$then = 'THEN ';
if(is_array($val[$field]['value']) && count($val[$field]['value']) == 2)
{
    /* The $val[$field]['value'][0] 
       and $val[$field]['value'][1] are unidentical type so we are 
       converting it to string by removing the single quote and using 
       settype for string type.
    */
    $first = str_replace("'", "", $val[$field]['value'][0]);
    $second = str_replace("'", "", $val[$field]['value'][1]);
    settype($first, "string");
    settype($second, "string");
    switch ($first) {
        case "+":
            $then .= $val[$field]['field'].' + ';
            break;
        case '-':
            $then .= $val[$field]['field'].' - ';
            break;
        case "*":
            $then .= $val[$field]['field'].' * ';
            break;
        case '/':
            $then .= $val[$field]['field'].' / ';
            break;
        case '%':
            $then .= $val[$field]['field'].' % ';
            break;
        
        default:
            $flag = FALSE;
            break;
    }

    if(is_numeric($second) && $flag == TRUE)
    {
        $then .= $val[$field]['value'][1];
    }

}
else
{
    $then = 'THEN '.$val[$field]['value'];
}
$final[$val[$field]['field']][] = 'WHEN '.$val[$index]['field'].' = '.$val[$index]['value'].' '.$then;

//$final[$val[$field]['field']][] = 'WHEN '.$val[$index]['field'].' = '.$val[$index]['value'].' THEN '.$val[$field]['value'];
```

Now when defining the array for update_batch just pass the value array with arithmetic operator and amount.

```
$values[] = array('id' => 1,'balance' => ['+',500]); //will increment.
```

**In above code you are identifying the value array and validating with the arithmetic sign and performing self field calculation.**

Laravel also not support of update batch arithmetic operations for self field but there is github repo : https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch#example-increment--decrement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).